# When and how often do macro expansions happen in SBCL Common Lisp implementation?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sbcl, lisp-macros

Some Lisp implementations (i) expand macros **once** and **save the result** for
**reuse**; (ii) others **reexpand** the macro at each macro call. Some
implementations (iii) even **attempt** to expand macro calls in **function bodies**
at the **time** the function is DEFUNed.

Which one is the case for SBCL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the REPL:

```
* (defparameter *expansions* 0)    
*EXPANSIONS*
* (defmacro foo ()
    (incf *expansions*)
    (print (list :expansions *expansions*))
    nil)
* (foo)

(:EXPANSIONS 1) 
NIL
* (defun bar () (foo))

(:EXPANSIONS 2) 
BAR
* (bar)
NIL
*
```

So there is one expansion for a function definition and none at runtime of that function.

Then one might try the file compiler, an interpreter, different debug options, etc. to check the number of macro expansions done by an implementation.